# How to parallelize when loading lots of data

Tags: matlab, constructor, parallel-processing, download

I have been struggling to speed up my MATLAB code which loads a number of large data files into custom class objects. My two classes are a `DataGroup` and a `DataObj`, where every `DataObj` loads a single independent .mat data file, and `DataGroup` contains an array of `DataObj` to be able to access information distributed throughout the multiple files. We have it distributed in this way because every file contains a structure with a completely different set of fields, so there's not a great way to compile them together. Since .mat files are a compressed format, I believe a large portion of the `load` time is actually being used by the decompression, not the HDD reading.

Below is a basic version of the code that I am trying to speed up. My problem is that the `parfor` doesn't help and actually makes things worse, because of the large overhead needed to broadcast the large rawData back to the client. I know the overhead is the cause because I accidentally had my `saveobj` overload setting `obj.rawData=[];` and that significantly improved the speed. The `name` and `ID` properties were being set properly, so I know the data was being loaded.

The saveObj overload is important, because the way MATLAB broadcasts variables between workers (and presumably back to the client) is to "save" them, and then "load" them in the destination. Since I have a custom class, if I overload saveObj it will be called before being sent back to the client. I also tried overloading `loadobj` to re-load the data a second time. This preserved the information, but at a slightly worse speed than serialized.

Here are my timing results on a small dataset. The different `parfor` methods indicate whether the `saveobj` and `loadobj` overloads were enabled, or commented out.

| Mode | Time |
| --- | --- |
| `for` loop | 16 s |
| `parfor` with `saveobj` and `loadobj` (data loaded twice) | 18 s |
| `parfor` with `saveobj` (data lost) | 7 s |
| `parfor` with no overloads | 160 s |

**Is there a better way to parallelize this to make things run quicker?** I've considered loading a couple key `DataObj`s first and then loading the rest in the background, updating the `DataGroup.dataSet` property in the background as well, but not sure how to do that. I tried using `parfeval` but can't figure out how to get the worker to update an object that's on the client.

run_script

```
% Data files are all .mat containing a single structure with many different fields
% The fieldnames are different for every data file
% Data files can range from a couple kB to over 1GB
filenames = {'file01.mat','file02.mat',...,'file100.mat'};
tic; allData = DataGroup(filenames); toc
```

DataGroup.m

```
classdef DataGroup < handle

properties
    dataSet
end

methods
function obj = DataGroup(filenames)
    dataSet = repmat(DataObj.empty(),1,length(filenames));
    parfor iFile = 1:length(filenames)
        dataSet(iFile) = DataObj(filenames{iFile});
    end
    obj.dataSet = dataSet;
end
end
```

DataObj.m

```
classdef DataGroup < handle

properties
    rawData
    name
    ID
    srcFile
end

methods
function obj = DataObj(filename)
    obj.rawData = load(filename);
    names = fieldnames(obj.rawData)
    obj.name = names{1};
    obj.ID = parse(obj.name); %some basic character parsing
    obj.srcFile = filename;
end

function b = saveobj(obj)
    b = obj;
    b.rawData = [];
end
end

methods (Static)
function obj = loadobj(b)
    obj = DataObj(b.srcFile);
end
end
```

Comment: Loading data from disk is not slow because of code, its slow because reading from a hard drive in an inherently slow thing. You can't "parallelise" it. Have you profiled your code to see what is the slow part?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I did profile it and the slow part is the `load` statement. If parallelization won't help, then why did it speed up when I included a `saveObj` overload that still loaded the data but removed it before it was "saved" back to the main thread?

Comment: Its not very clear what you mean by "main thread" because there is no code to back that up, but its parallel computing basics to not load up stuff in multi-treading loops, because the slow part is the communication between the HDD and the CPU, not anything to do with a CPU. This is why HDDs come with the speed of them as a feature, because you can not physically read faster than X and CPUs are much much faster than that X. This is also why RAM exists as a hardware piece, otherwise we would just load up from disk.

Comment: Note that MATLAB is pretty smart and has a JIT, maybe if you load up and then delete something in particular cases, it will just avoid loading it up, don't know. But I have no idea what you mean by `saveObj` overload, because again, [mcve]

Comment: @AnderBiguri Sorry, I'm not sure of all the correct terminology - when I say thread I think I really mean workers, and by "main thread" I think I should be saying client. I'll try to work on a more complete example code, but I'm not sure how complete it can be when it's about loading large data files.

Comment: @AnderBiguri The `saveObj` overload is important, because the way MATLAB broadcasts variables between workers (and presumably back to the client) is to "save" them, and then "load" them in the destination. Since I have a custom class, if I overload `saveObj` it will be called before being sent back to the client. When I removed the actual data before saving, the other fields which relied on information stored inside the file were still complete. That tells me that the datafiles were being loaded initially.

Comment: But the code you show, as far as I can see its onyl sequential, so there is no client, or workers or anything. That is a very specific structure of code that is missing from your question. There are also not classes in your question either! I can only see normal functions.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I thought that was clear from my description - I've tried running this with a `parfor` instead of the `for` which led to what we've been discussing.

Comment: And what I am saying from the start is that its not very clear and that that is the entire reason a [mcve] is required to get help, because there is no way you can sufficiently describe code with words. You are describing a code-behavior issue, without showing even how the code is called. impossible for us to get the same results

Comment: In any case, whatever the structure, `parfor XXX; load();end` will never work faster.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I've updated my code to try to be more complete. The reason parallelization can help is because a large portion of the `load` time is actually uncompressing the .mat file format, not simply reading from the HDD.

Comment: It's kind-of hard to know what to suggest here since we can't see how you need to *use* the data. If you need it all in-memory at the client.. then things might be tricky. Can you arrange things so that you load the data and then perform the processing on it all on a worker?

Comment: @Edric Once it's loaded there's really not a lot of processing done - it's basically a giant measurement log for thousands of different data fields. I might want to look up position and velocity for multiple objects over time, and my custom class looks up where to find that information and extract it in a usable format. Since it's all stored as structs in a .mat file, I can't do a partial read of a file.

Comment: I've considered loading a couple key `DataObj`s first and then loading the rest in the background, updating the `DataGroup.dataSet` property in the background as well, but not sure how to do that. I tried using `parfeval` but can't figure out how to get the worker to update an object that's on the client.